# MS-ACCESS: RichText alignment based upon field length

Tags: ms-access

Previously, I asked a question about changing the justification of a text box based upon the string length within the **text box** for a report.  The solution (seen below) works perfect for plain text and is loaded on `onPaint ()` and `onPrint()`.

```
If Len(myfield) < 100 Then myfield.TextAlign = 1 Else myfield.TextAlign = 4
```

I have a field that is in **rich text**, and I wish to accomplish the same.  When I attempted to use the same code for the **richtext** field, access blew up on me.

This project is work-related; therefore, I cannot download external files to assist.

Comment: What exactly does "Blew up on me" entail? Smoke ? Fire appliances?

Comment: LOL!  No, it went into a loop, the screen rapidly flickered, and would not let me do anything without going to into my task manager, closing Access, and re-opening Access.   Still, it would not distribute the text.            
                                                                                                                    
I would have typed killing Access, but I wouldn't want anyone from taking me literally.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you can't do this.

Rich text fields in Access contain HTML and support a [limited set of attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7228259/access-rich-text-which-subset-of-html-is-supported). HTML has its own formatting.

If you format a rich text box as centered (via the ribbon or popup menu), the following is stored as HTML source:

```
<div align=center>Your <strong>Rich Text</strong> goes here.</div>
```

If the text has no special alignment, it's just

```
<div>Your <strong>Rich Text</strong> goes here.</div>
```

So you might think: why not inject `align=justify` into the opening `<div>` in the record source?
Because it doesn't work. Access doesn't support this tag.

```
<div align=justify>Your <strong>Rich Text</strong> goes here.</div>
```

will simply be displayed left-aligned.

Comment: I can't imagine one, Google can't either.