# Textbox with TextFormat="Rich Text" doesn't work in 2013

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

I've developed an MS-Access front-end for an SQL 2016 database.  I developed in Access 2016.

Some of the dialog forms (help forms) show a long help text.  This comes from an SQL table: the column is NVARCHAR(MAX).  In SSMS, the contents look like this:

{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\nouicompat{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset238 Calibri;}{\f1\fnil\fcharset0 Calibri;}}
{*\generator Riched20 10.0.14393}\viewkind4\uc1 
\pard\f0\fs20\lang1038 [and then lots of text with formatting]

This data is shown on the form in a Textbox, with TextFormat set to "Rich Text".

In Access 2016 this works perfectly.  The client only have Access 2013 installed.  In 2013, the textbox shows the literal RTF text complete with codes and no formatting, rather than the formatted version.

What I've tried:

1. Checked that in Access 2013 the Textbox' TextFormat is still "Rich Text".  In other words, 2013 (officially) does support this setting.
2. Copied the (linked) SQL table's contents to a local Access table.  Set the column's Text Format property to "Rich Text".  (You can't do this on a linked table, hence the copying operation).  I get a warning about how this will HTML-encode the value, press Yes.  Save the table.  Make a test form based on this table, with a textbox with TextFormat="Rich Text".  No difference.

Does Access 2013 simply not support displaying Rich Text in textboxes, even though this property setting is still valid?
Or might it be something about the particular RTF encoding that Access 2013 (or even the client machine OS: unlikely, as the client machine is Win10 Pro - dev machine is Windows Server 2016) can't understand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You misunderstand what the *Rich Text* property does. *Rich Text* does not use RTF, it uses a limited form of HTML (allowing tags like `<i>`, `<b>`, etc.).

If you want to use RTF, you can either work with RTF files and an OLE object, or use a custom .ocx.

Stephen Lebans has written an RTF control, that can be found [here](http://www.lebans.com/richtext.htm) (no affiliation). I personally haven't used it, but feel free to try.

Comment: That can't be right, because setting this property on the Textbox displays my formatted text perfectly - in Access 2016.  Setting it to Plain Text (as expected) shows the literal text with all codes.  The problem is that this doesn't work in Access 2013.

Comment: It working in Access 2016 is odd. [The documentation](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Insert-or-add-a-rich-text-field-9f86237d-dbbc-4a85-b12c-9d8dca824630#bm2) states that it is _"stored and interpreted as rich HTML markup"_. The enum option for rich text is [acTextFormatHTMLRichText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/access-vba/articles/actextformat-enumeration-access). I can't explain you getting it to work under 2016, because afaik, that should not be possible.

Comment: It is odd.  How could I encode the formatting as HTML?  e.g. format it in Word, and save as HTML, or something?  That would put RTF and all its oddities (which I'd rather avoid) out of the picture.

Comment: There are many ways to achieve that. The clipboard-based approach shared [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/141fb4cb-5dd8-4b01-bd83-8146a05cf54f/convert-rtf-format-to-html-format?forum=accessdev) can work. I've fiddled with outlook in the past (create an e-mail with an RTF body, change format to HTML) but I don't have that code anymore. A problem with both these approaches is that it's not HTML you want, but a limited subset of HTML, and some HTML tags might interfere.

Comment: Thank you.  I might try that if we can't get the client to upgrade to 2016.  It sounds like a bit of a nightmare - a completely bizarre format that doesn't match anything outside in the real world!

Comment: @SebTHU: The best documentation for this bizarre format I could find is here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/7228259/87698