# Display HTML on Access Form

Tags: html, ms-access

I have a column that contains HTML (as shown below).  Is there a way to display its contents on a form so that it is readable and does not show all the encoding?

---

```
incident_description
"<html><head><br><meta http-equiv=""Content-Type"" content=""text/html; charset=utf-8""></head><body dir=""auto""><br><div><br><table bgcolor=""FFD133""><tr><td><b>CAUTION: This email originated from outside of the organization. Do not click links or open attachments unless you recognize the sender and know the content is safe.</b></font></td></tr></table> <br></div><div dir=""ltr"">Dear All,</div><div dir=""ltr""><br></div><div dir=""ltr"">Please note that computer was not delivered by FedEx today. It seem there is a delay. Hopefully it arrives Monday.&nbsp;</div><div dir=""ltr""><br></div><div dir=""ltr""><img src=""cid:A0C1FA4B-96A4-4F18-8960-47DCDC074A0E-L0-001""><br></div><div dir=""ltr""><br></div><div dir=""ltr"">Mabel&nbsp;</div><div dir=""ltr""><br><blockquote type=""cite"">On Dec 31, 2020, at 6:07 PM, Global Service Desk &lt;servicedesk@synteract.com&gt; wrote:<br><br></blockquote></div><blockquote type=""cite""><div dir=""ltr""><br><br><br><meta name=""Generator"" content=""Microsoft Word 15 (filtered medium)""><br><!--[if !mso]><style>v\:* {behavior:url(#default#VML);}<br>o\:* {behavior:url(#default#VML);}<br>w\:* {behavior:url(#default#VML);}<br>.shape {behavior:url(#default#VML);}<br></style><![endif]--><style><!--<br>/* Font Definitions */<br>@font-face<br> {font-family:""Cambria Math"";<br> panose-1:2 4 5 3 5 4 6 3 2 4;}<br>@font-face<br> {font-family:Calibri;<br> panose-1:2 15 5 2 2 2 4 3 2 4;}<br>@font-face<br> {font-family:Verdana;<br> panose-1:2 11 6 4 3 5 4 4 2 4;}<br>@font-face<br> {font-family:Corbel;<br> panose-1:2 11 5 3 2 2 4 2 2 4;}<br>/* Style Definitions */<br>p.MsoNormal, li.MsoNormal, div.MsoNormal<br> {margin:0in;<br> font-size:11.0pt;<br> font-family:""Calibri"",sans-serif;}<br>a:link, span.MsoHyperlink<br> {mso-style-priority:99;<br> color:#0563C1;<br> text-decoration:underline;}<br>span.EmailStyle18<br> {mso-style-type:personal-compose;<br> font-family:""Calibri"",sans-serif;<br> color:windowtext;}<br>.MsoChpDefault<br> {mso-style-type:export-only;<br> font-size:10.0pt;<br> font-family:""Calibri"",sans-serif;}<br>@page WordSection1<br> {size:8.5in 11.0in;<br> margin:1.0in 1.0in 1.0in 1.0in;}<br>div.WordSection1<br> {page:WordSection1;}<br>--></style><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><br><o:shapedefaults v:ext=""edit"" spidmax=""1026"" /><br></xml><![endif]--><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><br><o:shapelayout v:ext=""edit""><br><o:idmap v:ext=""edit"" data=""1"" /><br></o:shapelayout></xml><![endif]--><br><br><br><div class=""WordSection1""><br><p class=""MsoNormal"">Welcome Mabel,<o:p></o:p></p><br><p class=""MsoNormal""><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></p><br><p class=""MsoNormal"">We are very excited you have joined the Synteract family. You will find your Synteract login information below.<o:p></o:p></p><br><p class=""MsoNormal""><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></p><br><p class=""MsoNormal"">Your notebook has been shipped out and will arrive soon. To track your shipment, please use the following web page<br><a href=""https://urldefense.com/v3/__https://www.fedex.com/apps/fedextrack/?action=track__;!!D-bsrUTt-LOm!6EYZHGRK8ye59sLsl4azM83HiceZ4bVj1qKguAQdavkVc9jRkx4_ngsThUqg9fMMJwM$"">https://www.fedex.com/apps/fedextrack/?action=track</a> and the following tracking code:<br><b><span style=""background:yellow;mso-highlight:yellow"">946303508730</span></b><o:p></o:p></p><br><p class=""MsoNormal""><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></p><br><p class=""MsoNormal""><b>Once you receive your laptop, please log on using the credentials provided below and connect to your home WiFi or LAN, wait three minutes and restart the computer. After the restart, your computer should be connected properly.<br><o:p></o:p></b></p><br><p class=""MsoNormal""><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></p><br><p class=""MsoNormal"">If you need technical assistance do not hesitate to contact the Service Desk by phone:<span style=""font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif""><br></span><a href=""http://www.synteracthcr.com/Contact/Tech-Support"">http://www.synteracthcr.com/Contact/Tech-Support</a> or by email<br><a href=""mailto:ServiceDesk@synteract.com"">ServiceDesk@synteract.com</a>.<span style=""color:#1F497D""><br></span>All other questions should be directed to your manager.<o:p></o:p></p><br><p class=""MsoNormal""><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></p><br><table class=""MsoNormalTable"" border=""0"" cellspacing=""0"" cellpadding=""0"" width=""660"" style=""width:495.0pt;border-collapse:collapse""><br><tbody><br><tr><br><td width=""660"" style=""width:495.0pt;padding:3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt""><br><p class=""MsoNormal"" style=""mso-margin-top-alt:auto;mso-margin-bottom-alt:auto""><span style=""font-size:13.5pt;font-family:&quot;Verdana&quot;,sans-serif""><div>&lt;image003.jpg&gt;</div></span><span style=""font-size:13.5pt;font-family:&quot;Verdana&quot;,sans-serif""><o:p></o:p></span></p><br></td><br></tr><br></tbody><br></table><br><p class=""MsoNormal""><span style=""font-size:10.0pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif;display:none""><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></span></p><br><table class=""MsoNormalTable"" border=""0"" cellspacing=""0"" cellpadding=""0"" width=""660"" style=""width:495.0pt;border-collapse:collapse""><br><tbody><br><tr><br><td width=""660"" colspan=""3"" style=""width:495.0pt;border:none;border-bottom:solid windowtext 4.5pt;padding:3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt""><br><p class=""MsoNormal"" style=""mso-margin-top-alt:auto;mso-margin-bottom-alt:auto""><span style=""font-size:13.5pt;font-family:&quot;Verdana&quot;,sans-serif"">Account for Synteract systems</span><span style=""font-size:7.5pt;font-family:&quot;Times New Roman&quot;,serif""><o:p></o:p></span></p><br></td><br></tr><br><tr><br><td width=""551"" style=""width:413.25pt;padding:3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt""><br><p class=""MsoNormal""><b>Windows Username: <o:p></o:p></b></p><br><p class=""MsoNormal""><b><span style=""color:black;background:yellow;mso-highlight:yellow"">mjoachimo</span><span style=""color:black""><o:p></o:p></span></b></p><br></td><br><td width=""10"" style=""width:7.8pt;padding:3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt""></td><br><td width=""99"" style=""width:73.95pt;padding:3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt""><br><p class=""MsoNormal""><b>Windows Password: <o:p></o:p></b></p><br><p class=""MsoNormal""><b><span style=""background:yellow;mso-highlight:yellow"">Temp2021</span></b><b><o:p></o:p></b></p><br></td><br></tr><br><tr><br><td width=""551"" style=""width:413.25pt;padding:3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt""><br><table class=""MsoNormalTable"" border=""0"" cellspacing=""0"" cellpadding=""0"" width=""541"" style=""width:405.75pt;border-collapse:collapse""><br><tbody><br><tr><br><td width=""271"" style=""width:203.25pt;padding:3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt""></td><br><td width=""24"" style=""width:.25in;padding:3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt""></td><br><td width=""246"" style=""width:184.5pt;padding:3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt""></td><br></tr><br></tbody><br></table><br></td><br><td width=""10"" style=""width:7.8pt;padding:3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt""></td><br><td width=""99"" style=""width:73.95pt;padding:3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt""></td><br></tr><br><tr><br><td width=""551"" style=""width:413.25pt;padding:3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt""><br><p class=""MsoNormal""><b>E-Mail Address: <o:p></o:p></b></p><br><p class=""MsoNormal""><u><span style=""color:#0563C1;background:yellow;mso-highlight:yellow""><a href=""mailto:Mabel.Joachimo@synteract.com"">Mabel.Joachimo@synteract.com</a></span><span style=""color:#0563C1""><o:p></o:p></span></u></p><br></td><br><td width=""10"" style=""width:7.8pt;padding:3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt""></td><br><td width=""99"" style=""width:73.95pt;padding:3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt""></td><br></tr><br><tr><br><td width=""551"" style=""width:413.25pt;padding:3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt""></td><br><td width=""10"" style=""width:7.8pt;padding:3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt""></td><br><td width=""99"" style=""width:73.95pt;padding:3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt""></td><br></tr><br></tbody><br></table><br><p class=""MsoNormal""><span style=""font-size:12.0pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif""><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></span></p><br><table class=""MsoNormalTable"" border=""0"" cellspacing=""0"" cellpadding=""0"" width=""662"" style=""width:496.6pt;border-collapse:collapse""><br><tbody><br><tr><br><td width=""660"" style=""width:495.0pt;border:none;border-bottom:solid windowtext 4.5pt;padding:3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt""><br><p class=""MsoNormal"" style=""mso-margin-top-alt:auto;mso-margin-bottom-alt:auto""><span style=""font-size:13.5pt;font-family:&quot;Verdana&quot;,sans-serif"">Telephone: Extension, Voicemail</span><span style=""font-size:7.5pt;font-family:&quot;Times New Roman&quot;,serif""><o:p></o:p></span></p><br></td><br><td width=""2"" colspan=""2"" style=""width:1.5pt;padding:0in 0in 0in 0in""></td><br></tr><br><tr style=""height:30.6pt""><br><td width=""660"" style=""width:495.0pt;padding:3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt;height:30.6pt""><br><p class=""MsoNormal"" style=""margin-bottom:12.0pt"">Company Phone Number (Fuze): <b><br><span style=""font-size:10.5pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif;color:black;background:yellow;mso-highlight:yellow"">760-795-2156</span></b><span style=""color:#1F497D""><o:p></o:p></span></p><br></td><br><td width=""1"" style=""width:1.0pt;padding:0in 0in 0in 0in;height:30.6pt""></td><br><td style=""padding:0in 0in 0in 0in;height:30.6pt""></td><br></tr><br></tbody><br></table><br><p class=""MsoNormal""><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></p><br><p class=""MsoNormal"" style=""line-height:12.05pt;text-autospace:none""><b><span style=""font-size:12.0pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif;color:black""><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></span></b></p><br><p class=""MsoNormal"" style=""line-height:12.05pt;text-autospace:none""><b><span style=""font-size:12.0pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif;color:black""><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></span></b></p><br><p class=""MsoNormal"" style=""line-height:12.05pt;text-autospace:none""><b><span style=""font-size:12.0pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif;color:black"">Global Service Desk</span></b><span style=""font-size:10.0pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif""><br><span style=""color:#221E1F"">| </span><b><span style=""color:#CF202F;letter-spacing:.5pt"">synteract</span></b></span><span style=""color:#C00000"">®<o:p></o:p></span></p><br><p class=""MsoNormal""><span style=""font-size:10.0pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif;color:black"">Support: 760.268.8242 | Toll-free: 866.682.9827</span><span style=""font-size:10.0pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif;color:#221E1F""><o:p></o:p></span></p><br><p class=""MsoNormal""><span style=""font-size:10.0pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif;color:#221E1F"">For a list of international Support numbers:<o:p></o:p></span></p><br><p class=""MsoNormal""><a href=""https://www.synteract.com/Contact/Tech-Support""><span style=""font-size:10.0pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif;color:#0563C1"">https://www.synteract.com/Contact/Tech-Support</span></a><span style=""font-size:10.0pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif;color:#221E1F""><br><o:p></o:p></span></p><br><p class=""MsoNormal""><span style=""font-size:10.0pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif"">Email:<br></span><a href=""mailto:servicedesk@synteract.com""><span style=""font-size:10.0pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif;color:#0563C1"">servicedesk@synteract.com</span></a><span style=""font-size:10.0pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif;color:black""><o:p></o:p></span></p><br><p class=""MsoNormal""><a href=""http://www.synteract.com/""><b><span style=""font-size:8.0pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif;color:#0563C1"">www.Synteract.com</span></b></a><b><span style=""font-size:8.0pt;font-family:&quot;Corbel&quot;,sans-serif;color:#006666""><o:p></o:p></span></b></p><br><div><br><p class=""MsoNormal""><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></p><br></div><br><div><br><p class=""MsoNormal""><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></p><br></div><br><p class=""MsoNormal""><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></p><br></div><br><br><br><div>&lt;Employee IT Handbook_New Citrix.pdf&gt;</div></div></blockquote><br><div><br>IMPORTANT - PLEASE READ: This electronic message, including its attachments, is CONFIDENTIAL and may contain PROPRIETARY or LEGALLY PRIVILEGED or PROTECTED information and is intended for the authorized recipient of the sender. If you are not the intended recipient, you are hereby notified that any use, disclosure, copying, or distribution of this message or any of the information included in it is unauthorized and strictly prohibited. If you have received this message in error, please immediately notify the sender by reply e-mail and permanently delete this message and its attachments, along with any copies thereof, from all locations received (e.g., computer, mobile device, etc.).<br><br></div></body></html>"
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a simple and a powerful answer.

**The simple solution**: Bind your content to a text box and set it's `Text Format` property to `Rich Text`. Note, though, that "Access Rich Text" only supports [a subset of HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7228259/87698).

**The powerful solution**: Add a web browser ActiveX control to your form, e.g. [WebView2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/).